# Use MinGW in Eclipse on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, mingw

I was trying to make a C project in Eclipse 3.6.1, I chose the 'Cross-Compile Project' and the 'Cross Compiler' toolchain. However, when I compiled my project, the standard 'g++' compiler was used instead of 'i686-pc-mingw-g++', my MinGW compiler. Where can I configure the C/C++ compilers in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I used Eclipse for C development, but I think this is what you're looking for:

Right click your project -> select properties -> find build -> look around a bit for the command used to compile files, you want to set it to use MinGW instead.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This is exactly what I was wanting! Do you know of a way to make it default for all Cross Compile projects?

Comment: Just set it that way in the default settings of Eclipse I think. I do urge against that though, it's best to set it for each project individually so you are aware of it. I once set a flag for -lxml2 and in another project I completely forgot about that.